# How to compare single date with multiple dates in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

How do i compare two dates in php?.
I have the following dates. One is coming from DB. and another is from Datepicker

```
$dbdate = 01-06-201402-06-201403-04-201405-06-2014 //DB date 
$datepickerDate = 06-06-2014 //Datepicker date.
```

Here `$dbdate` is in foreach loop and both formats are dd-mm-yyyy. How do i compare a single date from datepicker to the date in `$dbdate`?

Comment: So, `$dbdate` is a concatenation of dates?

Comment: compare in loop or $dbdate is one string which contain multiple dates?

Comment: Not enough information. Show what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes $dbdate has concatenation of dates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with [STRTOTIME](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function in for loop like this

```
return STRTOTIME($dbdate) === STRTOTIME($datepickerDate);
```

Comment: Or you could just do `return STRTOTIME($dbdate) === STRTOTIME($datepickerDate);`.

Answer (score 0):

best thing is convert all to unix time stamp..
php method is strtotime() 
then it return integer value...u can compare that values

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php

but the thing is ur dbdate parsing more than 1 date at a time..u should get 1 date at a time

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution - but I hope it helps you out ;-).

```
<?php
// Input
$dbdate = '01-06-201402-06-201403-04-201405-06-2014';
$datepickerDate = '06-06-2014';

// Please note: it would be possible to check dates directly in this for loop.
// For educational purposes I splitted it.

$datepickerDateTime = strtotime($datepickerDate);

// Transform concatenated dates to separate dates in array.
$datesList = array();
$dateOffset = 10;
for($iCurrentDateOffset = 0; $iCurrentDateOffset < strlen($dbdate); $iCurrentDateOffset += $dateOffset) {
    $datesList[] = substr($dbdate, $iCurrentDateOffset, $dateOffset);
}

// Compare each separate date to $datepickerDate
foreach($datesList as $date) {
    if(strtotime($date) < $datepickerDateTime) {
        echo("$date is before $datepickerDate<br />");
    } else if(strtotime($date) == $datepickerDateTime) {
        echo("$date is equal to $datepickerDate<br />");
    } else if(strtotime($date) > $datepickerDateTime) {
        echo("$date is past $datepickerDate<br />");
    }
}

// ...
```

Output is:

- 01-06-2014 is before 06-06-2014
- 02-06-2014 is before 06-06-2014
- 03-04-2014 is before 06-06-2014
- 05-06-2014 is before 06-06-2014